# How to input data into a 2D array represented by a double pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to use the Terminal to input data into a 2d array represented by a double-pointer.

```
int main() {
    int M, N;

    printf("Please enter the number of rows in the array:");
    scanf("%d", &M);
    printf("Please enter the number of columns in the array:");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    int **A = (int**)malloc(M * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        A[i] = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));

    // Assigning and printing 2d array
    printf("Please enter the elements in the array:");

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);      <------- break here
        }
    }

    printf("The array you entered was:");
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code is built successfully, but the programme stops at the indicated location when I try to run it :(

[This is what it looks like in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wekMq.png)
[This is the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eISg.png)

Why? :(

Comment: Maybe because this is not a [mre]? This is also C, and not C++.

Comment: This might depend on your input data. How many numbers get read in (i.e. what are the values of `i` and `j` ) before the program crashes? Also, although XCode may not require you to wrap your code in a `main` function, you don't actually have a valid C program without it.

Comment: There’s no error checking.  The memory allocation might fail; the inputs might fail.

Comment: I downloaded your code, compiled it [adding the missing `main` and `#include`], and ran it [on linux with `gcc`]. It worked correctly. I am unable to reproduce your problem [using data `3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6`]. Although it _is_ possible to run out of memory (e.g. `malloc` returns `NULL`), I don't believe that would be your problem unless `M` or `N` was huge. Have you tried your program with simple/small input? If your program is, indeed, aborting on the `scanf` for the array elements, can you get a stack traceback from the debugger at that point?

Comment: What do you mean by *the programme stops at the indicated location when I try to run it*? Does the program exit? How may numbers do you input? How do you run the program?

Comment: Is there something other than whitespace and digits in your input?

Comment: I have realised that the code was actually correct, but I accidentally added a break point. The code runs fine once the break point is removed.

Answer (score 1):

From the illustrations, you seem to have set a breakpoint at the location indicated.
Try and clear the breakpoints and run your program again.